# Connect Yandex Translate API v2 to nodejs

Tags: node.js, api

Can anyone help with connecting Yandex Translate API v2 to nodejs.
API documentation has python example. But i cant correctly translate it to nodejs

Docs https://cloud.yandex.com/en-ru/docs/translate/operations/translate

PY EXAMPLE

```
import requests

IAM_TOKEN = '<IAM-токен>'
folder_id = '<идентификатор каталога>'
target_language = 'ru'
texts = ["Hello", "World"]

body = {
    "targetLanguageCode": target_language,
    "texts": texts,
    "folderId": folder_id,
}

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {0}".format(IAM_TOKEN)
}

response = requests.post('https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate',
    json = body,
    headers = headers
)

print(response.text)
```

uncorrect NODE EXAMPLE

```
const axios = require("axios");

const IAM_TOKEN =
  "XXXXXXXX";
const folder_id = "XXXXXXX";
const target_language = "ru";
const texts = ["Hello"];

const json = {
  targetLanguageCode: target_language,
  texts: texts,
  folderId: folder_id,
};

const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: "Bearer (IAM_TOKEN)",
};

const response = axios.post(
  "https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate",
  json,
  headers
);

console.log(response.text);
```

Big thanks if someone can help me

Codes python and node in post

Comment: response: {
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',

Comment: Looks like problem with Bearer or post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will works.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const IAM_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXX";
const folder_id = "YYYYY";
const target_language = "ru";
const texts = ["Hello"];
const json = {
    targetLanguageCode: target_language,
    texts: texts,
    folderId: folder_id,
};

const response = axios.post(
    url = 'https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate',
    data = JSON.stringify(json),
    config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${IAM_TOKEN}`
        }
    }
);
// access token is 'response.data.access_token'
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4));
```

Comment: @LOCALSHOT, thanks for you up-vote for my answer, can you accept too? If you click up arrow, give me 15 points more. Thanks!